# Bulk operations view reorder

Tags: views

I have a view with some default (views) bulk operations. I needed some more (such as publish content, ...), so I added them (http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3633/drupal-7-how-to-add-your-own-custom-operation-in-views-bulk-operation-vbo), but now I need to reorder  them (so that the "publish content" is first, ... is second and so on) and can not find any way to do that (I tried to use form_alter function (with dsm on the form) on the page, where the view is shown, to debug information about the form in order to find the array containing all the bulk operations (and then rearrange it), but did not found such an array).

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I posted a reply but I misunderstood the question. I checked the VBO code. If I didn't overlook, the module does not explicitly sort the actions list. That means the actions will be added in their definied order (order of the `hook_actions_info()` )return array and the module weight.

Comment: It seems, that it is not in the defined order. I have the following code (abbreviated): `return array(
        'publish_selected_content_action' => array( ...
      ),
        'depublish_selected_content_action' => array( ...
      ),
      'indicate_files_permanent_action' => array( ...
      ),
       'indicate_files_temporary_action' => array( ...
      ),    'promote_selected_files_action' => array(...
      ),
        'demote_selected_files_action' => array( ...
      ),`                                                     but the order is: demote, indicate permanent, temp., promote, ...

Comment: hide and then publish. It seems that the order is just random.

Comment: Now I tried reordering the items in hook_actions_info(), but is still the same (no effect on the item order)

Comment: If it's an existing View, try this: remove the VBO field, save view, add field again. You will see the actions list is attached to the View object itself.  I can't guarantee anything but that's all I can do at the moment :)

Comment: Tried that, but did not help. Then I realized, that I can try exporting the view and change the order there. After doing that and importing back, everything was as wanted. Thanks